# Xcode & wxWidgets Framework

Tags: c++, xcode, user-interface, frameworks, wxwidgets

I've downloaded wxWidgets - wxwidgets.org

I ran the configure file using terminal.

How can I use this framework with Xcode C++ project?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at the following documentation, or consider pin pointing down a more specific question about using the framework (ie, what problems you may have run into).

http://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Development:_wxMac

http://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Guides_%26_Tutorials#Mac_OS

http://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Creating_Xcode_projects_for_wxWidgets_applications (Out of date, but may still help you. As someone who used wxWidgets in the past, I can tell you that the code is correct).